# Apex code to close parent only when all child are closed

Tags: apex, trigger

We use Cases and Work Orders.  I have the following class executed from a trigger based upon this: [Apex Code Samples for Work orders](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=wo_apex_samples.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

```
public static void closeCaseFromWorkOrder(Map<ID, WorkOrder> newWorkOrderMap){
    for (WorkOrder wo: newWorkOrderMap.values()){
       Case ca = [Select Status, case_closed_reason__c, completed_date__cfrom case where id = :wo.CaseId];
       ca.status = 'Closed';
       ca.Case_Closed_Reason__c = wo.Case_Closed_Reason__c;
       ca.Completed_Date__c = wo.Completed_Date__c;
       ca.Reason__c = wo.Reason__c;
       update ca;
    }
 }
```

This does work in that it closes the Case attached to a Work order but I would like to extend it to close the case only if all child work orders are closed.

I've been playing around and from some examples people have already helped me with I know that roughly I need to separate things out for bulkification but I am still struggling with some of the concepts:

```
public static void closeCaseFromWorkOrder(Map<ID, WorkOrder> newWorkOrderMap){
    Set<Id> cases2Close = new Set<Id>();
    //these are the cases we may need to close
    for (WorkOrder wo: newWorkOrderMap.values()){
        cases2Close.add(wo.CaseId);
    }
    //these are the work orders that are related to the cases we may close
    Map<Id, WorkOrder> queryWOMap = new Map<Id, WorkOrder>([SELECT id FROM WorkOrder where CaseId IN: cases2Close AND status != 'Closed']);
    
   //Now I think I have to go through the map to see which cases have ONLY closed work orders But i am stuck...
```

I have a Work Order Trigger that calls a Trigger Handler class.  This method is called from this class `OnBeforeUpdate`.

So my question is: how do I close the parent record from a child record when all of the child records are closed.

EDIT: Latest Attempt:

```
 public static void closeCaseFromWorkOrder(Map<ID, WorkOrder> newWorkOrderMap){
    Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
    Integer varValidateCount = 0;     
    
    for (WorkOrder wo: newWorkOrderMap.values()){
        caseIds.add(wo.CaseId);  
    }
    Set<Id> blacklistset = new Map<Id, SObject>([SELECT CaseId Id FROM WorkOrder WHERE CaseId IN :caseIds AND statuscategory != 'closed' GROUP BY CaseId]).keyset();
            
    for (WorkOrder wo: newWorkOrderMap.values()){
        if (!blacklistset.contains(wo.CaseId)){
            system.debug('case id = ' + wo.CaseId);
            //this is where we find and update the case to closed as there is no blacklist conflict.
        }
        else{
             system.debug('ELSE case id = ' + wo.CaseId);  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an Id blacklist in a variety of ways. Here's one neat trick for it.

```
Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
for (WorkOrder record :  records)
    caseIds.add(record.CaseId);

Set<Id> blacklist = new Map<Id, SObject>([
    SELECT CaseId Id FROM WorkOrder 
    WHERE CaseId IN :caseIds AND Status != 'closed'
    GROUP BY CaseId
]).keyset();
```

You want to collect the CaseId values, not Id.  The trick above uses `AggregateResult` to alias this lookup as `'Id'`, then allowing you to use the built in map constructor.

A slower, more traditional version would use the child records directly, at which point you have to iterate over them:

```
Set<Id> blacklist = new Map<Id, SObject
for (WorkOrder record : [
    SELECT CaseId FROM WorkOrder 
    WHERE CaseId IN :caseIds AND Status != 'closed'
]) blacklist.add(record.CaseId);
```

Once you have the blacklist, you can check it add follows:

```
for (WorkOrder record : records)
{
    if (!blacklist.contains(record. CaseId))
    {
        // any existing siblings are closed
    }
}
```

Comment: I''ve tried to use the above but I am getting a bit stuck - i've edited my original question with the code.  Your theory does make sense but I must be going wrong somewhere with the code.

Comment: @sfdc fixed it. Had to fly so I couldn't proof read.

Comment: Thanks, I must be going wrong somewhere.  I have tried both methods above and when I create a case with 2 child work orders I can see debug the code and it correctly grabs the caseid but the (!blacklist.contains(record.CaseId)) doesn't get triggered (I think it might be null rather than an incorrect value).  Ive updated my latest code again.

Comment: The above created this error whn trying to close: System.ListException: Row with null Id at index: 0:  on the set blacklist line.

Comment: Did you include the alias? `SELECT CaseId Id FROM ...`

Comment: Thanks, I have got past the error but it isn't quite working.  If I start with a case and create 2 open work orders it closes it.  I then re-open the case and close 1 work order, the case stays open.  If I close the 2nd work order it stays open.   If I re-open a work order the case closes..the logic must be slightly off

Comment: Kind of hard to follow. I'll try to set up some time to chat through it since comments would be tedious. Just pretty busy this week.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically i can give a suggestion you can give a try with that.

You have parent as **Case** and **WorkOrder** As children's. **WorkOrder** has all the Parent ID its belong to, In your case **WorkOrder** object has **CaseId** field which contain parent case id.

So you can do following way to solve your problem.

1. Get the **AggregateResult** on group by **caseId** for **workOrder** Object.

   > select caseId ,count(caseId) from workOrder group by caseId
2. Get the **AggregateResult** on group by **caseId** for **workOrder** Object and also match **status** == '**Closed**' in SOQL.

   > select caseid,count(caseid) from workorder group by caseId having  status == 'Closed'

Now match the both **AggregateResult count value**. if the Count value is equal,  then all the child is closed and capture **caseID** same time from **AggregateResult**. otherwise it is not closed.